Bypass the Azure logout account selection screen when logging out from the applicaition @azure/msal-angular V3.0.23
Issue:
Invoking "msalService.logoutRedirect()" and passing the account value still does not bypass the azure logout screen (Which account do you want to sign out of?)
Version used in Angular application:
Angular - 17.3.0
@azure/msal-angular - 3.0.23
@azure/msal-browser - 3.21.0

Screen to be bypassed:

Code:-
**while Logging In:**
this.msalService.instance.setActiveAccount(payload.account);
 
**Logout Steps:**
let currentAccount = msalInstance.getAllAccounts()?.at(0);
 
let session: EndSessionRequest = {
     account: currentAccount
};
 
this.msalService.logoutRedirect(session);


Check if this helps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/759538/bypass-the-the-account-selection-screen-while-logo
